# Auto posterisation

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

All the posterisation algorithms I'm seen ask for an output colour count.

Instead, I'd like the output colour count to be automatically generated, and the algorithm to automatically merge similar colours together.

Essentially, the parameter for posterisation changes from "output colour count" to "colour difference threshold" which could be a percentage.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: look at meanshift

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I don't get it. Seems to be a clustering algorithm

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I was able to use `magick convert input -kmeans N output` as a clustering method of colour reduction - however this is just like the `+ditcher -colors N` - it specifies the output color count which isn't what I want - I tried `magick convert input.png  -mean-shift 9x9+10% output.png` but this just seems to blur the image

Comment: I meant the meanshift **algorithm**, not whatever _filter_ imagemagick calls "mean-shift". its "mean-shift" apparently is just for noise removal, not for quantifying/clustering colors. -- let go of imagemagick. it's not a cureall. -- mentally prepare yourself for the possibility that you'll have to write some code.